# Who voiced Goo man in "Let Them Eat Goo"?

Tags: south-park, voice-acting

**Who does the voice-acting of Goo man in South Park episode "[Let Them Eat Goo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8660722/)"?**

Goo man character is built on Daniel Plainview from "[There will be Blood](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469494/)", acted by Daniel-Day Lewis. The voice can be heard officially [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hp5le70kIuc). I have found lot of other South Park voice actors [here](https://www.liveabout.com/south-park-cast-137656), with different characters that Trey Parker and Matt Stone voice, but its from January 2019. It is not Daniel-Day Lewis (obviously), but who does the voice-acting?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like Trey to me.

Comment: No additional voice actors are listed in [the episode's credits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XH4O.png). It sounds like Trey to me too, but it's possible that they had an *uncredited* voice actor, so I'm posting this as a comment instead